# Is there a way to "activate" html application in Blue Prism?

Tags: internet-explorer, blueprism

I am building an object in Blue Prism, and the easiest way of dealing with a window is sending a global key to the window. In "Windows based Application" you can use navigation box to Activate\Bring Forward that window. That way you can ensure that the global key will be send to that window.

I cannot find a way to do the same with Browser Based Application. Has anyone found a way to activate browser based application?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.

All I had to do was use Application Modeler to scan whole window using "win32" mode. Then I could use navigation box, to activate that window.

Comment: Perfect solution.